# Custom theme is not applied to the react-native-elements components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-elements

I've created a custom theme and passed it to ThemeProvider, but it hasn't been applied to react-native-elements components. I'm using react-native-elements version 4.0.0-rc. Here is my code:

Custom theme

```js
import { createTheme } from '@rneui/themed';

export const theme = createTheme({
  lightColors: {
    primary: 'red',
    background: '#fff',
    platform: {
      web: {
        primary: 'red',
      },
    },
  },
  darkColors: {
    primary: 'red',
    background: '#000',
    platform: {
      web: {
        primary: 'red',
      },
    },
  },
  mode: 'light',
});
```

`App.tsx`

```js
import { ThemeProvider } from '@rneui/themed';
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import Root from './Root';
import { theme } from './themed';

function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Root />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}

export default registerRootComponent(App);
```

`Root.tsx`

```js
import { Button } from '@rneui/base';
import { useTheme, useThemeMode } from '@rneui/themed';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

export default function Root() {
  const { theme } = useTheme();
  const { mode, setMode } = useThemeMode();

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Hello world!</Text>
      <Button
        color="primary"
        title={'Click me'}
        size="md"
        radius={'md'}
        onPress={() => setMode(mode === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark')}
      />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    marginTop: 10,
  },
});
```

Result
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKgeE.png)

The Button must have red background instead of the default blue. Should I have passed the theme to Button's prop? like this

```js
export default function Root() {
  const { theme } = useTheme();
  const { mode, setMode } = useThemeMode();

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Hello world!</Text>
      <Button
        theme={theme}
        color="primary"
        title={'Click me'}
        size="md"
        radius={'md'}
        onPress={() => setMode(mode === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark')}
      />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

I want my custom theme to be applied by default to all components instead of always having to pass the theme to its prop. Can anyone help?

Comment: I am not a user of this library but a work around if you don't find a better option is to have a themed button that already has the theme passed to it, then use the themedButton instead of the default Button from the package. It would just be an easy override in a file. example Import {Button} from "package" export const TButton = (props) => <Button theme={customtheme} {..props} />.

Answer (score 3):

You need to import button from "@rneui/themed" instead of base